# Не отображает текст заголовка html

Tags: кодировка, http, html

Пишет всякие иероглифы в заголовке страницы, если там русский текст. Пытался использовать windows 1251 и utf-8 кодировки. При запуске с компа всё работает, а если запускаю с хоста hut.ru, то появляется данная проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. поставь кодировку uft8 без BOM
2. пропиши в htaccess AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: спасибо, помогло.